# Tesseract integration to my Project on xCode 6.3 iOS 8.3

Tags: ios, objective-c, ocr, tesseract

I'm really digging the web and stackoverflow questions but none of them does not solve my problem.

I'm trying use **Tesseract** OCR in my iOS Project, but integration did not go what I expected. I follow the instructions in [this blog](http://lois.di-qual.net/blog/install-and-use-tesseract-on-ios-with-tesseract-ios/) and I did the all things but still I m not able to integrate it. May be because of the new updates, anyway I just want to solve my problem.

So I have added all files to my project about **tesseract** and **leptonica** and I have added **tessdata** to my project.

I also tried the run existing project on [github](https://github.com/robmathews/OCR-iOS-Example) but still the problem exists.

Error is[image: here]

I checked eng.cube.lm file exists in project and I also linked it.

Please help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I could not found my answer, but I found another way to do it. I used **cocoapods** to get **OCR library** . This is the simplest way to adding **dependency** to your project.

This very clear how to use [cocoapods quick guide](https://medium.com/5-step-ios-tutorials/how-to-use-cocoapods-137df1bbb89a),

This is the pod that I used [tesseract OCR pod](https://cocoapods.org/?q=tesseract)

This is the [installation guide](https://github.com/gali8/Tesseract-OCR-iOS/wiki/Installation) to **tesseract OCR**

If you follow the tips, everything will be good.

On the other hand, I think my problem was file broken or out of date to new versions. My first way was very dirty and rough. To use **tesseract** on **iOS** , best way is the **Cocoapods**

I hope this will help someone!